# Windows Server 2008 (Domain Controller) local user problems

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008, dns

we have an issue with Windows Server 2008 when using it as a domain controller:

We have an application that uses the local Windows database for keeping the user accounts. When a user inserts the username *Padmin* in all systems the login works perfectly. But in Windows Server 2008 (DC) the user is not found. The application doesn't accept domain user accounts.

So there is a way to use a domain account as a local account in this machine? Or to create a link or something else?

Thanks,

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you promote a machine to a Domain Controller, it removes all local accounts. It is not possible to have local accounts on a DC, and it will not authenticate them. You must use Domain accounts.

Comment: There is no way to login without using the domain name? In this computer?

Comment: you don't necessarily need to use the domain name, but you must use an account that is in Active Directory, you cannot use a local account. They are removed fro security reasons.